# Bind Textblock to static class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind to a static class and can't seem to get it to work right. Here is what I have for the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Game:ActivePlayers x:Key="ActivePlayerInfo" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock x:Name="p1_Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ActivePlayerInfo}, Path=PlayerInfo.Player1.Name}" 
                           TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Showcard Gothic" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
```

I can access the ActivePlayerInfo class because if I change the Path to equal "Name" (a temporary dependency property that I created) it works. Here is the code for the ActivePlayerInfo Class:

```
   public class ActivePlayers : DependencyObject
{
    public GameInfo PlayerInfo { get { return GameInfo.Singleton; } }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(ActivePlayers), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    public ActivePlayers()
    {
        Name = PlayerInfo.Player1.Name;

    }

}
```

GameInfo.Singleton:

```
       public class GameInfo
    {
        private static GameInfo gameDetails = new GameInfo();
        public static GameInfo Singleton
        {
            get { return gameDetails; }

        }
    public PlayerDetails Player1 = new PlayerDetails();
```

And finally PlayerDetails contains:

```
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PlayerDetails), new UIPropertyMetadata("New Player"));
```

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work right" -- What is the behavior you expect, and what is the behavior you're seeing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Player1` field to a property.